# Use Google Maps navigation without Google Location Accuracy improvement

Tags: google-maps, location-services

Since today Google Maps necessitates me to turn on improvement of Location Accuracy when starting to navigate. If I tap "No thanks" navigation stops again. If I switch to another App and come back to Google Maps navigation also stops. This startet today using Android Auto without any update. I was changing the route and couldn't continue navigation without enabling this.

I don't want to enable using Wifi and mobile networks, because then Google collects my location data all the time. In addition, what makes it even worse, when this setting is on, Google links my public IP address with my location after some time. Thats why I really don't want this function enabled.

[image]

There is good GPS signal reception and location is detected within seconds, so this option is not necessary at all and while driving even not helpful at all, because GPS is then the only possibility to get a good location. On roads there is no Wifi Google could use to locate and celltower location is way too inaccurate.

Comment: Did you find any answer?